# How to give an image as input and get another image as output in keras tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have zigsaw puzzle images and I have the corresponding pairs.I want to give the image as input to the model and find the corresponding pair of it.I have made the below model which achieves a bad accuracy of 30% while in the training.But when I pass the test images array  it predicts an array having all nan values.Should I change my loss function? Please check the code below the image[image]

```
in_shape=(32,256,256,3)
model1=models.Sequential(
[
    resize_and_rescale,
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=in_shape,padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=in_shape,padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    

    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=in_shape,padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
 

    layers.Conv2D(128,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=in_shape,padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(256,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu',padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
 
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),

    layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),
 
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),

    layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'),
    layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same'),


    layers.Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid')
     
]
)
model1.build(input_shape=in_shape)

model1.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're predicting pixel values `[0, 255]`, then you'll want to change your last layer to:

`layers.Conv2D(3, (1, 1), activation='linear')`

A sigmoid activation function will try to force your outputs to a range of `[0, 1]`, whereas a linear activation will allow for regression to pixel values of the range `[0, 255]`, assuming that's what you want.

Comment: Some further explanation as to why this should be done would make this a better answer.